# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Models\Model

Tags: php, slim

I'm making a simple app and learning Slim 3 framework.
As I wanted a MVC design and working with a DIC, I tried a simple tutorial and put my work on top of it.

- The goal is to show datas from my database on the view, using PDO.

This is very simple theorically.

Problem, I have no clue how to get my dependencies on my models in order to call PDO and I've got this error.

Without passing my DIC on my Models, the design and the app works just fine.
I can call my Models from my Controllers and passing anything on my Views without any errors.

Below is my code, thanks in advance for your enlightments.

Starting with **The Route** I get :

```
$app->get('/content', \App\Controllers\ContentController::class);
```

**The Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class ContentController
{
    protected $container;
    
    // Passes the DIC to get the model.
    function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    
    function __invoke($request, $response, $args)
    {
        
        $datas = $this->container->get('contentModel');
        
        $args['content'] = $datas->testContent();
        
        // get the template renderer and pass response and datas to the template file.
        return $this->container->get('renderer')->render($response, 'content.php', $args);
    }
```

Here is my **Models** :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Model 
{
    // Passes the DIC to get db later.
    function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    
    
    protected function executeQuery($sql, $params = null) {
        if ($params == null)
        {
            $result = $this->container->get('db')->query($sql); // direct execution
        } else {
            $result = $this->container->get('db')->prepare($sql); // prepared execution
            $result->execute($params);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    
}
```

My **Content Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

Class ContentModel extends Model
{
    
    public function testContent()
    {
        $testDatas = "Hello world";
        return $testDatas;
    }
    
    public function getContent()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts';
        $posts = $this->executeQuery($sql);
        return $posts;
    }
    

}
```

Here is my **dependencies** :

```
<?php

use Slim\App;

return function (App $app) {
$container = $app->getContainer();

// View renderer
$container['renderer'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['renderer'];
    return new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer($settings['template_path']);
};

// Database
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $db = $c['settings']['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db['host'] . ';dbname=' . $db['dbname'],
        $db['user'], $db['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};


// Model data stored
$container['contentModel'] = new \App\Models\ContentModel();

};
```

I get this error whenever I want to passes the DIC inside a Model, however the constructor works just fine on my Controllers.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Models\Model::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp\www\slimappmvc\src\dependencies.php on line 35 and exactly 1 expected in C:\wamp\www\slimappmvc\src\Classes\Models\Model.php on line 8
>
> ( ! ) ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Models\Model::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp\www\slimappmvc\src\dependencies.php on line 35 and exactly 1 expected in C:\wamp\www\slimappmvc\src\Classes\Models\Model.php on line 8

Answer (score 0):

ContentModel uses the same constructor as your Model class because you didn't overwrite it when you extended it, and the constructor for Model requires 1 argument when you instantiate the class, "$container". So when you create an instance ContentModel, you need to pass it an argument too:

```
$container['contentModel'] = new \App\Models\ContentModel($container);
```

I'm assuming the $container variable is what the Model class is expecting.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. One thing I still didn't get is why that same constructor works just fine when I instantiate the class from my Controller ?
Am I missing something really important here ?